# Figure Twitter API Callback to HTTPS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, https, localhost, twitter-oauth

I am using ASP .NET MVC 3 to develop a site running on IIS express server. The site has to run on https protocol.

I would like to add Twitter OAuth support to the site. Twitter requires a callback url and it should not be `https://localhost:44300/`. Normally, for http, I know the solution is to use `http://127.0.0.1` instead. However, I have tried `https://127.0.0.1:44300`, it did not work for me and I got a HTTP 503 error.

Is there something I can do to get the callback working with https?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1- For IIS :

> > 1-1 make sure that  application pool is not paused or disabled 
> >      check here [Solve HTTP Error 503](http://www.brainbrushups.com/2013/07/solve-http-error-503-service-is.html)
> >
> > 1-2 Make sure that SSL is enabled for IIS [enabling SSL for IIS](http://www.lansweeper.com/kb/54/How-to-configure-SSL-in-IIS-Express.html)

2- Make sure that port 44300 is not used with anyother application, to check that run command:

> > "Netstat -a"

3- review Twitter Errors code

> > if everything is Okay on your machine,you might need to check twitter API errors code
> >
> > For example error 503 means :

```
The Twitter servers are up, but overloaded with requests. Try again later.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am pretty sure it's an issue related to my localhost. I was able to access https://localhost:44300/ but I can't get to the same site using https://127.0.0.1:44300. So according to your trouble-shoot steps, 1 and 2 are working, and it's not a problem of twitter.

Comment: Try this this work around:  in your host file define company.com with IP address 127.0.0.1 , also add the header company.con to your default site at IIS